# Change time of cache expiry

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've built my first woocommerce website. It worked great until I've migrated it from my local machine to shared godaddy hosting. This shared hosting has many many limits in loading speed and I've encountered a strange behaviour. I've sent a request to get my website but I have to wait approx. 40 seconds so it loads. After that, all the requests to the server had normal response time (1-5s). But then, after noone had used my website in 1 hour, this behaviour happened again - first load takes 40 secs., after that website is loading normally. I've digged a lot on that and I found that might be the cache issue (I know it might be obvious, but I'm a newbie and it took me a lot to figure it out :D). But I have not really found any solution or help to my issue anywhere in the internet so I'm asking you here for the help. So now, finally, my question is: how do I change the time of expiry for wordpress/woocommere application cache? If I change it to, let's say, 24h, it should work for me I guess. But then comes second question - when I change the cache expiry time for my website, what if I change it's content and let's say add new products to the store. Would it return the cached website without new products? Because if I understand it well, it would be wise to cache as long as possible constant elements (plugins, themes, etc.) but only them, nothing else. I would be really grateful for any help and guidance to eliminate "the first 40s loading time".

Comment: if it take 40 seconds to load , then i guess its better to refine your code first. because a good website should load within 5 seconds. And to change cache expiry there are cache meta tags which you can find

Comment: I found that it's content related, but it's nothing special - wp + woocommerce + elementor. And only first request takes 40s. Later the website works normally and loading time is normal. Just the first load after at least 1h of not using the website

Comment: that is bad. go open dev tools and check which are taking time and find solutions to reduce it .

Comment: I use pingdom to monitor this but it looks like it's the woocommerce itself. I've removed maxmind geofence to reduce loading speed but there is really nothing more than pure wp + woocommerce + elementor + oceanwp theme. If this happens only at first website load, it looks like changing cache expiry from 1h to 24h should do the job. I guess if that's not it, it's still worth to check if this solution works. But still, I can't even find how do I do this